# Rsync Encryption

Tags: rsync

I know that rsync can enable / disable the ssh encryption protocol during the file transfer. So, if the ssh encryption protocol has been disabled, does it mean that rsync does not do any encryption at all?

Also, the reason why I asked the above question is we use the rsync module as part of our file transfer and there is nothing in the module that specifies that ssh encryption will be used.

If rsync does not use any encryption, then I can theoretically open a port on both source and destination machines and push the file from source to destination.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

rsync performs no encryption on its own. If you don't use ssh, nor do you tunnel the rsync traffic through stunnel or some kind of VPN, then no encryption is performed. Yes, you can save some CPU cycles this way.

Answer (score 70):

If you use the `rsync://` protocol scheme (i.e. when you connect to a `rsyncd` daemon) then no encryption will be used (although password authentication is done using a MD4-based challenge-response system and is probably still reasonably secure).

If you use the `hostname:/some/path` scheme then rsync transparently calls SSH, which encrypts *everything*, and uses SSH's native authentication mechanisms. As far as I can tell, some OpenSSH versions supported an option `Ciphers null` in the configuration file, but this has been removed in later versions.

Generally you shouldn't worry about encryption overhead, unless you are working in a 1 Gbit network or you have old computers.

Comment: How much will the size overhead difference between rsync:// and ssh? 
If the data is encrypted, wont the size of the data increase? 
I'm concerned because, my internet provider has limit on the transfer limit like 2GB per month.

Comment: For large transfers, the bandwidth overhead is negligible, within a few percent. Encryption doesn't "expand" data per se, but each chunk of data needs extra headers to communicate IV and checksums.

Comment: Whilst the encryption does not cause issues with additional bandwidth, it can be bottlenecked by the CPU (on GigE with low powered machines). An example is the HP N40L Microserver, which has a 1.4GHz processor. It maxes out over SSH with default options at around 30MBps (~180Mbit/s). iPerf shows that it is capable of full GBit transfer speeds. Disk transfer shows the disks are capable. CPU runs at 100%. Fixing this requires changing to a less secure cipher, or removing encryption. The arcfour cipher runs at about 60MBps on the same device.

Comment: "MD4-based challenge-response system and is probably still reasonably secure" - seriously?...

Comment: @JSmyth Yes, seriously. I agree that MD4 should have been deprecated ages ago, but for certain uses it's still secure. There's a fast collision attack on MD4, but that doesn't affect challenge-response authentication. You'd need a preimage attack to break that, but no practical preimage attack exists.

Comment: [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) uses MD5 from version 3.0.0 . MD4 is used for older versions.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni, your link is to rsync(1), which does not discuss auth at all (pretty reasonable as it primarily concerns rsyncd).  You probably confused authentication with checksums.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov You are right, MD5 is used for file checksum. MD4 is still used for authentication, as 28 Jan 2018 : https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsyncd.conf.html Documentation recommend to use rsync over ssh for "top-quality security"...