# How does `scp` differ from `rsync`?

Tags: rsync, scp

An article about [setting up Ghost blogging](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-host-ghost-with-nginx-on-digitalocean) says to use `scp` to copy from my local machine to a remote server:

```
scp -r ghost-0.3 root@*your-server-ip*:~/
```

However, [Railscast 339: Chef Solo Basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/339-chef-solo-basics?view=asciicast) uses `scp` to copy in the opposite direction (from the remote server to the local machine):

```
scp -r root@178.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/chef .
```

In the same Railscast, when the author wants to copy files to the remote server (same direction as the first example), he uses `rsync`:

```
rsync -r . root@178.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/chef
```

Why use the `rsync` command if `scp` will copy in both directions? How does `scp` differ from `rsync`?

Comment: apart from being simpler and always encrypted, nobody has pointed out anything that scp can do better than "rsync -aA". i prefer "rsync -aAX --delete source dest". checkout bsync for two-way sync.

Answer (score 521, accepted):

The major difference between these tools is how they copy files.

`scp` basically reads the source file and writes it to the destination. It performs a plain linear copy, locally, or over a network.

`rsync` also copies files locally or over a network. But it employs a special [delta transfer algorithm](http://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/) and a few optimizations to make the operation a lot faster. Consider the call.

```
rsync A host:B
```

- `rsync` will check files sizes and modification timestamps of both **A** and **B**, and skip any further processing if they match.
- If the destination file **B** already exists, the delta transfer algorithm will make sure only differences between **A** and **B** are sent over the wire.
- `rsync` will write data to a temporary file **T**, and then replace the destination file **B** with **T** to make the update look "atomic" to processes that might be using **B**.

Another difference between them concerns invocation. `rsync` has a plethora of command line options, allowing the user to fine tune its behavior. It supports complex filter rules, runs in batch mode, daemon mode, etc. `scp` has only a few switches.

In summary, use `scp` for your day to day tasks. Commands that you type once in a while on your interactive shell. It's simpler to use, and in those cases `rsync` optimizations won't help much.

For recurring tasks, like `cron` jobs, use `rsync`. As mentioned, on multiple invocations it will take advantage of data already transferred, performing very quickly and saving on resources. It is an excellent tool to keep two directories synchronized over a network.

Also, when dealing with large files, use `rsync` with the `-P` option. If the transfer is interrupted, you can resume it where it stopped by reissuing the command. See Sid Kshatriya's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21476688).

Finally, note that `rsync://` the protocol is similar to plain HTTP: unencrypted and no integrity checks. Be sure to always use `rsync` via SSH (as in the examples from the question above), not via the rsync protocol, unless you really know what you're doing. `scp` will always use SSH as underlying transport mechanism which has both integrity and confidentiality guarantees, so that is another difference between the two utilities.

Comment: You say to use scp for your day to day tasks. From your explanation and the OP, it appears that the interface for the two tools when used without options is identical. If rsync has the superior implementation and the interfaces are the same, why not always use rsync?

Comment: Their interface is not the same, even without options. Rsync has special interpretation of a trailing slash on the source argument (synchronize the directory itself versus its contents). It might have other gotchas, I'm not sure.

Comment: Also, I would guess `scp` is more likely to be available on a Unix-like system, so you prevent an annoying "command not found" now and then.

Comment: How does rsync handle getting killed halfway through or losing network halfway through? I often see people do scp+mv+traps to make sure that they can also behave well in error cases. If rsync can handle these cases well enough it might be a better day to day tool, even if it has some overhead, right?

Comment: @erikb85 rsync has the -P flag which will display a progress bar and enable resuming from a partially completed transfer. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps

Comment: Another interface difference between `scp` and `rsync`: `rsync -a` versus `scp -rp` to preserve modification times and permissions.

Answer (score 106):

rysnc can be useful to run on slow and unreliable connections. So if your download aborts in the middle of a large file rysnc will be able to continue from where it left off when invoked again.

Use `rsync -vP username@host:/path/to/file .`

The -P option preserves partially downloaded files and also shows progress.

As usual check `man rsync`

Answer (score 71):

Difference b/w scp and rsync on different parameter

### 1. Performance over latency

- `scp` : scp is relatively less optimise and speed
- `rsync` : rsync is comparatively more optimise and speed

https://www.disk91.com/2014/technology/networks/compare-performance-of-different-file-transfer-protocol-over-latency/

### 2. Interruption handling

- `scp` : scp command line tool cannot resume aborted downloads from lost network connections
- `rsync` : If the above rsync session itself gets interrupted, you can resume it as many time as you want by typing the same command. rsync will automatically restart the transfer where it left off.

http://ask.xmodulo.com/resume-large-scp-file-transfer-linux.html

### 3. Command Example

#### scp

```
$ scp source_file_path destination_file_path
```

#### rsync

```
$ cd /path/to/directory/of/partially_downloaded_file
$ rsync -P --rsh=ssh userid@remotehost.com:bigdata.tgz ./bigdata.tgz
```

The `-P` option is the same as `--partial --progress`, allowing rsync to work with partially downloaded files. The `--rsh=ssh` option tells rsync to use ssh as a remote shell.

### 4. Security :

scp is more secure. You have to use `rsync --rsh=ssh` to make it as secure as scp.

**man document to know more :**

- scp : http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/scp/
- rsync : http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/

[image: performance chart]

Comment: on many systems ssh is used by default. https://serverfault.com/questions/378939/do-you-need-e-ssh-for-rsync

Comment: About Security, from [openSSH 8.0 release notes](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.0):

`The scp protocol is outdated, inflexible and not readily fixed. We
recommend the use of more modern protocols like sftp and rsync for
file transfer instead.`

Answer (score 18):

One major feature  of `rsync` over `scp` (beside the delta algorithm and encryption if used w/ ssh) is that it automatically **verifies** if the transferred file has been transferred correctly. Scp will not do that, which occasionally might result in corruption when transferring larger files. So in general **rsync is a copy with guarantee**.

Centos manpages mention this the end of the `--checksum` option description:

> Note that rsync always verifies that each transferred file was
>   correctly reconstructed on the receiving side by checking a whole-file
>   checksum that is generated as the file is transferred, but that
>   automatic after-the-transfer verification has  nothing to do with this
>   option’s before-the-transfer “Does this file need to be updated?”
>   check.

Answer (score 5):

There's a distinction to me that `scp` is always encrypted with ssh (secure shell), while `rsync` isn't necessarily encrypted. More specifically, `rsync` doesn't perform any encryption by itself; it's still capable of using other mechanisms (ssh for example) to perform encryption.

In addition to security, encryption also has a major impact on your transfer speed, as well as the CPU overhead. (My experience is that `rsync` can be significantly faster than `scp`.)

Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821526/rsync-encryption) for when `rsync` has encryption on.

Answer (score 2):

**scp** is best for *one* file.
**OR** a combination of `tar` & compression for smaller data sets
like source code trees with small resources (*ie*: images, sqlite *etc*).

---

**Yet**, when you begin dealing with **larger** volumes say:

- **media folders (40 GB)**
- **database backups (28 GB)**
- **mp3 libraries (100 GB)**

It becomes impractical to build a *zip/tar.gz* file to transfer with **scp** at this point do to the *physical* limits of the hosted server.

As an exercise, you can do some *gymnastics* like piping `tar` into `ssh` and redirecting the results into a *remote* file. (saving the need to build
a swap or temporary clone *aka* zip or tar.gz)

**However**,

**rsync** simplify's this process and allows you to transfer *data* without consuming any additional disc space.

**Also**,

Continuous (cron?) updates use minimal changes vs full cloned copies speed
up large data migrations over time.

tl;dr 
`scp`   == *small scale* (with room to build compressed files on the same drive) 
`rsync` == *large scale* (with the necessity to backup large data and no room left)

Answer (score -3):

it's better to think in a practical context. In our team, we use `rsync -aP` to replace a bad cassandra host in our cluster. We can't do this with scp (slow and no progress preservation).

Comment: Not really bringing anything not yet mentioned in the other answers. Plus we shouldn't even answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @DanCornilescu this describes a use case in a real scenario, which makes it easy for others to understand the difference. I don't see any other similar answers

Comment: See -P explained and slowness/speed-related notes in Sid's and Rafa's answers.