# Copy file from remote host to local host

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have the following username@machine connection

user1@machine1 -> user2@machine2

How can I copy files from machine2 to machine1?

Comment: If you can be more clear you'll get a better answer.

Comment: I have access to my local machine1 with user1 username, From machine1 I can ssh to machine2 with user2 username.
I can only connect from machine1 to machine 2 : 
So I can run only the following on machine1 
From machine2 I have no connection to machine1. 
I have to copy files from machine2 to machine1

Comment: You can do that with scp. I added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

Use it like this:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/dir /this/dir/
```

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-copy-files-with-rsync-over-ssh) is step by step tutorial. You can read about differences between `rsync` and `scp` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20257021/1387612)

Comment: This command should not work because my and remote machine shells are different.

Comment: @davidgh You can specify shell (rsh or ssh) http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scp`

Use it like this

```
scp <source path> <destination path>
```

Where the remote file is addressed as `user_name@host_name:path/to/file`

---

Suppose you want to get a file named `a.txt` which is in the home directory of user `user2` on machine2 say, `192.168.1.10`. You can do this on your machine1,

```
scp user2@192.168.1.10:a.txt .
```

Comment: After running this command I get "loaded COMMON (current)" message on my terminal and my file does not copied.

Comment: @davidgh That's strange. Works just fine for me.

Comment: @davidgh Firstly, is this what you wanted ?