# How to make Ubuntu bash script wait on password input when using scp command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh, scp

I want to run a script that deletes a files on computer and copies over another file from a connected host using scp command

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Moving Production Folder Over"
cd ~
sudo rm -r Production
scp -r host@192.168.123.456:/home/user1/Documents/Production/file1 /home/user2/Production
```

I would want to cd into the Production directory after it is copied over. How can I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how commands work? `bash` runs each command one at a time (unless you manually parallelize). If there's a command after `scp`, that command won't run until the `scp` completes. If `scp` is waiting for user input, `scp` hasn't completed; and the next command wont run.

Comment: Btw, you might want to look into `rsync` if you want to sync files between machines. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories might be a starting point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244585/how-does-scp-differ-from-rsync is also worth reading

Comment: il look into rsync, thanks!

Comment: you should use ssh-keys. Then you do not need a password for your ssh connection any more.

Comment: And take into account that if you `cd` inside the script it won't affect the parent shell